# Replacing the "if statement condition"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def move_dot(window, center, radius, velocity):
    size = (window.get_width(), window.get_height())
    for index in range(0, 2):
        # update center at coordinate
        center[index] = center[index] + velocity[index]
        # dot edge outside window?
        if (center[index] <= radius) or (center[index] + radius >= size[index]):
        # change direction
            velocity[index] = - velocity[index]
```

---

This is my code above for a program that bounces inside the window. The question I have is what do I use to replace `if (center[index] <= radius) or (center[index] + radius >= size[index]):` line *ONLY* so its center touches a window edge instead of bouncing when one of its edge touches a window edge. (I'll attach the full question below for anyone to have a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

---

[what code should replace the 'if statement condition' if you want the dot to bounce when its center touches a window edge instead of bouncing when one of its edges touches a window edge? You can only change the condition. You cannot add or remove any other code.]

---

I tried using the code `if (center[index] <= 0) or (center[index] + radius >= size(window(500,400))):` & `if (center[index] <= 0) or (center[index] + radius >= size[window]):` and I would get the error `Incorrect: It should bounce when either coordinate of the center is less than or equal to 0 or larger than or equal to the size (width or height) of the window.` . Can someone guide me or help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want the ball to bounce when the ball *center* hits a window edge. It's currently coded to bounce when the ball *edge* hits.

Just remove the radius gap when checking the ball position:

```
if (center[index] <= 0) or (center[index] >= size[index]):
```

Comment: It worked, I had to remove the "if" and ":" parts to submit. Thank you very much